# how to store complete script content to a variable and execute later

Tags: python, shell

I have a script.py we execute and inside this python script we need to read the content of a scripts and execute in another server

We have few shell scripts and one of the sample shell script "execution_count.ksh" as below.

We have these scripts available in one server. Is there  a way we can store the complete content of the script into a variable and use that variable as execution in other different server.

I tried with "with open" clause and passed "datainfo" as a command but its was getting failed

```
with open('script.sh', 'r') as file:
    datainfo = file.read()

command="ssh user@192.168.1.101 "+ datainfo
os.system(command)


exec 10<&0
exec < $1
# remember the name of the input file
in=$1

# init
file="current_line.txt"
let count=0

# this while loop iterates over all lines of the file
while read LINE
do
    # increase line counter 
    ((count++))
    # write current line to a tmp file with name $file (not needed for counting)
    echo $LINE > $file
    # this checks the return code of echo (not needed for writing; just for demo)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
     then echo "Error in writing to file ${file}; check its permissions!"
    fi
done

echo "Number of lines: $count"
echo "The last line of the file is: `cat ${file}`"

# Note: You can achieve the same by just using the tool wc like this
echo "Expected number of lines: `wc -l $in`"

# restore stdin from filedescriptor 10
# and close filedescriptor 10
exec 0<&10 10<&-
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with the tag `python`?

Comment: Complete script content was on py file "script.py" and we are trying to run "py script.py"

Comment: Split the sh script and py script in the question. And tell us how did you invoke it? Python won't allow `ssh user@192.168.1.101 datainfo`, it's not valid python syntax.

Comment: we are using "os" library to execute script command

Comment: Why didn't you post the actual python code then? How do you expect ppl to help if you are keeping the context secret?

Comment: @Gameplay I am sorry. No secret here. I am trying to get help as we have multiple lines in the script and trying to show that

Comment: What you've shown appears to be a mixture of Python and bash (?).

Comment: Maybe add some traceback? Or describe what was the result? Nobody knows what might "failed" mean in this particular scenario. Maybe the ssh requires password for auth...

Comment: Why not copying the script to the server?